# Possibility of having parameterized definitions in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to compactly write multiple definitions in haskell via case, without having to repeat, other than the input parameters, the exact same syntax?  The only possible solution I can imagine so far is a macro.

Below is an example of defining binary max and min functions.  Can we compress

```
max' x y
  | x > y = x
  | otherwise = y

min' x y
  | x < y = x
  | otherwise = y
```

into something like

```
(max',min') x y
  | x (>,<) y = x
  | otherwise = y
```

?

Edit:

I know this allows us to parametrize over the "grumpy face", but it seems like there still could be a more succinct form.

```
maxmin x y f
  | f x y = x
  | otherwise = y

max' x y = maxmin x y (>)
min' x y = maxmin x y (<)
```

Comment: I, for one, support this grumpy face syntax `(>,<)`

Comment: There are *shorter* ways to write `maxmin`—@melpomene’s answer, which puts the function (`(<)` or `(>)`) first so the `x` and `y` parameters can be elided, is a good one—but probably not any *clearer* way. For example, you can do some point-free code golf and write their function as `select = liftA2 (<*>) (flip bool)` using `bool` from `Data.Bool`, which expands to `select f x y = if f x y then x else y`. *Sometimes* that kind of trickery is profitable, but usually in Haskell it’s much clearer to just write the explicit guards or `if`.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can always do this:

```
select op x y
    | x `op` y  = x
    | otherwise = y

max' = select (>)
min' = select (<)
```

I.e. extract the common parts into a function and turn the differences into parameters.